# Spring Security with Spring Boot: Allowing unauthenticated user access on specific endpoints when using a filter

Tags: spring, rest, authentication, spring-security, spring-boot

I'm struggling with the basics of Spring Security here.

**What I wish to achieve**

My system is only for REST API handling, there's a login endpoint POST on `/user/sign_in` and a few open endpoints - GET on `/prompt/, /prompt/{id}, /story/, /story/{id}`, rest everything is for authenticated users only.

---

I have a custom authentication filter which I've put before the `BasicAuthenticationFilter`. I'm sharing my WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter code here

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(securedEnabled = true)
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private DemoAuthenticationProvider demoAuthenticationProvider;

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        http.authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/version", "/story", "/prompt").permitAll()
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/user/sign_in").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .addFilterBefore(new DemoAuthenticationFilter(), BasicAuthenticationFilter.class);
        http.csrf().disable();
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.authenticationProvider(demoAuthenticationProvider);
    }
}
```

For the anonymous user for the open endpoints, I'm returning a null authentication token in the filter and I'm getting

> 403 Access Denied

Why should authentication token be required when I've mentioned to permit all and not just authenticated for those end points? And how do I go about implementing it correctly?

Answer (score 5):

My bad!

End-points of spring-boot = request mapping of controller + request mapping of method. The GETs I mentioned are mapped at `/`. On changing to

```
.antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/version/", "/story/", "/prompt/").permitAll()
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/user/sign_in/").permitAll()
```

things are rolling.

Answer (score 3):

This works for mine :

```
 .and().authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/URL1/**", "/URL2/**").anonymous().anyRequest().authenticated();
```

Answer (score 0):

For me it worked with

```
.antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/api/specific/**").permitAll()
.antMatchers("/api/**").authenticated()
```

Note in this case that the specific endpoint is set with permitAll() before the generic one that requires authentication. It will not work the other way around.